# how to remove a column from export config

Tags: yii2

i am creating an export to excel configuration but i want to export some particular columns any idea??

```
'exportConfig' => [
        GridView::EXCEL => [

            'showHeader'=>$title,
            'showFooter' => true,
            'showCaption' => true,
            'filename'=>$title.date("Ymd",strtotime($searchModel->start_date)), 
            'mime' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
            'config' => [
                'worksheet' => 'ExportWorksheet',
                'cssFile' => ''
            ]
        ],
         ],
    'export'=>[
        'label'=>"Download",
        'icon' =>'export',
        'showConfirmAlert'=>false,
        'target'=>GridView::TARGET_SELF,
        'header'=>false
    ],
```

Comment: which extension you are using  ??

Answer (score 0):

if you are using KartikGridView  you could set the column you want to export in the GridView Widget

```
'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'your_col1',
            'your_col2',
            'your_col3',
            ....
          ];


   <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,        
    'showPageSummary' => true,

    'exportConfig' => [
        GridView::EXCEL => [

            'showHeader'=>$title,
            'showFooter' => true,
            'showCaption' => true,
            'filename'=>$title.date("Ymd",strtotime($searchModel->start_date)), 
            'mime' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
            'config' => [
                'worksheet' => 'ExportWorksheet',
                'cssFile' => ''
            ]
        ],
         ],
    'export'=>[
        'label'=>"Download",
        'icon' =>'export',
        'showConfirmAlert'=>false,
        'target'=>GridView::TARGET_SELF,
        'header'=>false
    ],
```